# How to detect current focused textbox in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 20 textbox and 40 buttons within a form, I would like to click any of 40 buttons then it will insert the value to the current focused or active textbox of 20 textbox.

But I don't know how to handle this in C#, please any idea would be great?

Thanks,

Comment: WinForms? WPF?  which one

Comment: See my answer below, it applies for WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an array of your textBoxes like (example of 4 textboxes)
let's say you have 4 textBoxes with names  `tbx0`, `tbx1`, `tbx2`, `tbx3`

```
TextBox[] array = new TextBox[4]{tbx0, tbx1, tbx2, tbx3};
```

then when you want to insert a text :

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
   if(array[i].Focused)
   {
      array[i].Text = yourText;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a variable for the last focused text box and set it on textbox_LostFocus. Because when you click the button the text box will have lost control. Then you can just call that text boxes .Text property and set it

ex code:

```
    textBox.LostFocus += (sender, e) => { lastTextBox = sender as TextBox; }
```

in button click event:

```
    .
    .
    lastTextBox.Text = textToSet;
    .
    .
```

edit:

In order to satisfy the condition of having multiple controls you could just use a loop when you are creating the text boxes and handle setting the event for each one with just one line. If this doesn't satisfy your requirement let me know and I can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
TextBox focusedTxt = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Focused);
```